# cls-hooked: AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: context not currently entered; can't exit

Tags: node.js, typescript, heroku, cls-hooked

I'm currently deploying an express app to Heroku. I'm using `cls-hooked` to set request ids for each request. This works perfectly on my local machine and inside Docker environments. But when deployed to Heroku, the application will randomly throw an error and won't restart. killing the API

I have not been able to reproduce this error anywhere but on Heroku

Note the IDs are sequential, I had to trim the error to fit StackOverflow limits

node version: 16.14.2

cls-hooke version:

```
        "node_modules/cls-hooked": {
            "version": "4.2.2",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/cls-hooked/-/cls-hooked-4.2.2.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-J4Xj5f5wq/4jAvcdgoGsL3G103BtWpZrMo8NEinRltN+xpTZdI+M38pyQqhuFU/P792xkMFvnKSf+Lm81U1bxw==",
        },
```

```
// async-context.ts
import cls from "cls-hooked";
import { randomUUID } from "crypto";

export const AsyncContext = cls.createNamespace(randomUUID());
```

```
// init-context.ts
export const initContextMiddleware: RequestHandler = (req, res, next) => {
     AsyncContext.run(() => next());
};
```

```
// set-request-id.ts
import { randomUUID } from "crypto";

export const setRequestIdMiddleware: RequestHandler = (req, res, next) => {
     AsyncContext.set("REQUEST_ID", req.headers["x-request-id"] || randomUUID());
     return next();
};
```

```
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607584+00:00 app[web.1]: AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: context not currently entered; can't exit.
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607586+00:00 app[web.1]: Namespace {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607586+00:00 app[web.1]: name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607586+00:00 app[web.1]: active: null,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607587+00:00 app[web.1]: _set: [],
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607587+00:00 app[web.1]: id: -1,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607588+00:00 app[web.1]: _contexts: Map(85) {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607599+00:00 app[web.1]: 5901 => {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607599+00:00 app[web.1]: _ns_name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607599+00:00 app[web.1]: id: 5620,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607600+00:00 app[web.1]: request_id: 'dd534fe7-31ca-486d-aa13-ea4a2b259b9f',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607600+00:00 app[web.1]: request_session: [Object]
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607600+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607600+00:00 app[web.1]: 5902 => {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607600+00:00 app[web.1]: _ns_name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607600+00:00 app[web.1]: id: 5620,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607600+00:00 app[web.1]: request_id: 'dd534fe7-31ca-486d-aa13-ea4a2b259b9f',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607601+00:00 app[web.1]: request_session: [Object]
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607601+00:00 app[web.1]: },
...
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607628+00:00 app[web.1]: 5943 => {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607629+00:00 app[web.1]: _ns_name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607629+00:00 app[web.1]: id: 5620,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607629+00:00 app[web.1]: request_id: 'dd534fe7-31ca-486d-aa13-ea4a2b259b9f',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607630+00:00 app[web.1]: request_session: [Object]
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607630+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607630+00:00 app[web.1]: 5945 => {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607631+00:00 app[web.1]: _ns_name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607631+00:00 app[web.1]: id: 5620,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607631+00:00 app[web.1]: request_id: 'dd534fe7-31ca-486d-aa13-ea4a2b259b9f',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607631+00:00 app[web.1]: request_session: [Object]
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607631+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607631+00:00 app[web.1]: 5946 => {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607631+00:00 app[web.1]: _ns_name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607632+00:00 app[web.1]: id: 5620,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607632+00:00 app[web.1]: request_id: 'dd534fe7-31ca-486d-aa13-ea4a2b259b9f',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607632+00:00 app[web.1]: request_session: [Object]
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607632+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607632+00:00 app[web.1]: 5947 => {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607632+00:00 app[web.1]: _ns_name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607634+00:00 app[web.1]: id: 5620,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607635+00:00 app[web.1]: request_id: 'dd534fe7-31ca-486d-aa13-ea4a2b259b9f',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607635+00:00 app[web.1]: request_session: [Object]
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607635+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607635+00:00 app[web.1]: 5949 => {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607635+00:00 app[web.1]: _ns_name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607635+00:00 app[web.1]: id: 5620,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607635+00:00 app[web.1]: request_id: 'dd534fe7-31ca-486d-aa13-ea4a2b259b9f',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607635+00:00 app[web.1]: request_session: [Object]
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607636+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607636+00:00 app[web.1]: 6036 => {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607636+00:00 app[web.1]: _ns_name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607636+00:00 app[web.1]: id: 5972,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607636+00:00 app[web.1]: request_id: '81c066a5-5359-4d93-8033-db59b1fd7089',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607636+00:00 app[web.1]: request_session: [Object]
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607636+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607636+00:00 app[web.1]: 6037 => {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607636+00:00 app[web.1]: _ns_name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607637+00:00 app[web.1]: id: 5972,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607637+00:00 app[web.1]: request_id: '81c066a5-5359-4d93-8033-db59b1fd7089',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607637+00:00 app[web.1]: request_session: [Object]
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607637+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607637+00:00 app[web.1]: 6040 => {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607637+00:00 app[web.1]: _ns_name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607637+00:00 app[web.1]: id: 5972,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607637+00:00 app[web.1]: request_id: '81c066a5-5359-4d93-8033-db59b1fd7089',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607638+00:00 app[web.1]: request_session: [Object]
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607638+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607638+00:00 app[web.1]: 6194 => {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607638+00:00 app[web.1]: _ns_name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607638+00:00 app[web.1]: id: 5972,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607638+00:00 app[web.1]: request_id: '81c066a5-5359-4d93-8033-db59b1fd7089',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607638+00:00 app[web.1]: request_session: [Object]
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607638+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607638+00:00 app[web.1]: 6199 => {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607639+00:00 app[web.1]: _ns_name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607639+00:00 app[web.1]: id: 5972,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607640+00:00 app[web.1]: request_id: '81c066a5-5359-4d93-8033-db59b1fd7089',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607640+00:00 app[web.1]: request_session: [Object]
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607640+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607640+00:00 app[web.1]: 6436 => {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607640+00:00 app[web.1]: _ns_name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607641+00:00 app[web.1]: id: 6372,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607641+00:00 app[web.1]: request_id: '17432c59-7ffa-44b4-9c4a-a113a19250aa',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607641+00:00 app[web.1]: request_session: [Object]
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607641+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607641+00:00 app[web.1]: 6437 => {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607641+00:00 app[web.1]: _ns_name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607642+00:00 app[web.1]: id: 6372,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607642+00:00 app[web.1]: request_id: '17432c59-7ffa-44b4-9c4a-a113a19250aa',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607642+00:00 app[web.1]: request_session: [Object]
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607642+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607642+00:00 app[web.1]: 6440 => {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607642+00:00 app[web.1]: _ns_name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607642+00:00 app[web.1]: id: 6372,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607643+00:00 app[web.1]: request_id: '17432c59-7ffa-44b4-9c4a-a113a19250aa',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607643+00:00 app[web.1]: request_session: [Object]
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607643+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607643+00:00 app[web.1]: 6548 => {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607643+00:00 app[web.1]: _ns_name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607643+00:00 app[web.1]: id: 6372,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607643+00:00 app[web.1]: request_id: '17432c59-7ffa-44b4-9c4a-a113a19250aa',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607644+00:00 app[web.1]: request_session: [Object]
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607644+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607644+00:00 app[web.1]: 6553 => {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607644+00:00 app[web.1]: _ns_name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607644+00:00 app[web.1]: id: 6372,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607644+00:00 app[web.1]: request_id: '17432c59-7ffa-44b4-9c4a-a113a19250aa',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607644+00:00 app[web.1]: request_session: [Object]
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607644+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607645+00:00 app[web.1]: 6790 => {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607645+00:00 app[web.1]: _ns_name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607645+00:00 app[web.1]: id: 6749,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607645+00:00 app[web.1]: request_id: 'f94c9d35-e829-4443-9012-ea0682e40af9',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607645+00:00 app[web.1]: request_session: [Object]
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607645+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607645+00:00 app[web.1]: 6791 => {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607646+00:00 app[web.1]: _ns_name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607646+00:00 app[web.1]: id: 6749,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607646+00:00 app[web.1]: request_id: 'f94c9d35-e829-4443-9012-ea0682e40af9',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607646+00:00 app[web.1]: request_session: [Object]
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607646+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607647+00:00 app[web.1]: 6794 => {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607647+00:00 app[web.1]: _ns_name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607647+00:00 app[web.1]: id: 6749,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607647+00:00 app[web.1]: request_id: 'f94c9d35-e829-4443-9012-ea0682e40af9',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607648+00:00 app[web.1]: request_session: [Object]
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607648+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607648+00:00 app[web.1]: 6936 => {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607648+00:00 app[web.1]: _ns_name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607648+00:00 app[web.1]: id: 6749,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607648+00:00 app[web.1]: request_id: 'f94c9d35-e829-4443-9012-ea0682e40af9',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607649+00:00 app[web.1]: request_session: [Object]
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607649+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607649+00:00 app[web.1]: 6941 => {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607649+00:00 app[web.1]: _ns_name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607649+00:00 app[web.1]: id: 6749,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607649+00:00 app[web.1]: request_id: 'f94c9d35-e829-4443-9012-ea0682e40af9',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607649+00:00 app[web.1]: request_session: [Object]
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607649+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607649+00:00 app[web.1]: 7041 => {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607650+00:00 app[web.1]: _ns_name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607650+00:00 app[web.1]: id: 6749,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607650+00:00 app[web.1]: request_id: 'f94c9d35-e829-4443-9012-ea0682e40af9',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607650+00:00 app[web.1]: request_session: [Object]
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607650+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607650+00:00 app[web.1]: 7232 => {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607650+00:00 app[web.1]: _ns_name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607651+00:00 app[web.1]: id: 7171,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607651+00:00 app[web.1]: request_id: 'f4586618-522f-42b0-9021-3d5d5226d13c',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607651+00:00 app[web.1]: request_session: [Object]
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607651+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607651+00:00 app[web.1]: 7233 => {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607651+00:00 app[web.1]: _ns_name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607651+00:00 app[web.1]: id: 7171,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607652+00:00 app[web.1]: request_id: 'f4586618-522f-42b0-9021-3d5d5226d13c',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607652+00:00 app[web.1]: request_session: [Object]
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607652+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607652+00:00 app[web.1]: 7236 => {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607652+00:00 app[web.1]: _ns_name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607653+00:00 app[web.1]: id: 7171,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607653+00:00 app[web.1]: request_id: 'f4586618-522f-42b0-9021-3d5d5226d13c',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607653+00:00 app[web.1]: request_session: [Object]
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607653+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607653+00:00 app[web.1]: 7371 => {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607653+00:00 app[web.1]: _ns_name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607654+00:00 app[web.1]: id: 7171,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607654+00:00 app[web.1]: request_id: 'f4586618-522f-42b0-9021-3d5d5226d13c',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607654+00:00 app[web.1]: request_session: [Object]
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607654+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607654+00:00 app[web.1]: 7376 => {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607655+00:00 app[web.1]: _ns_name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607655+00:00 app[web.1]: id: 7171,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607657+00:00 app[web.1]: request_id: 'f4586618-522f-42b0-9021-3d5d5226d13c',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607657+00:00 app[web.1]: request_session: [Object]
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607657+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607667+00:00 app[web.1]: 7452 => {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607668+00:00 app[web.1]: _ns_name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607668+00:00 app[web.1]: id: 7171,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607668+00:00 app[web.1]: request_id: 'f4586618-522f-42b0-9021-3d5d5226d13c',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607668+00:00 app[web.1]: request_session: [Object]
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607668+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607668+00:00 app[web.1]: 7453 => {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607668+00:00 app[web.1]: _ns_name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607669+00:00 app[web.1]: id: 7171,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607669+00:00 app[web.1]: request_id: 'f4586618-522f-42b0-9021-3d5d5226d13c',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607669+00:00 app[web.1]: request_session: [Object]
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607669+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607669+00:00 app[web.1]: 7454 => {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607669+00:00 app[web.1]: _ns_name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607669+00:00 app[web.1]: id: 7171,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607669+00:00 app[web.1]: request_id: 'f4586618-522f-42b0-9021-3d5d5226d13c',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607670+00:00 app[web.1]: request_session: [Object]
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607670+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607670+00:00 app[web.1]: 7455 => {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607670+00:00 app[web.1]: _ns_name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607670+00:00 app[web.1]: id: 7171,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607670+00:00 app[web.1]: request_id: 'f4586618-522f-42b0-9021-3d5d5226d13c',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607670+00:00 app[web.1]: request_session: [Object]
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607671+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607671+00:00 app[web.1]: 7456 => {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607671+00:00 app[web.1]: _ns_name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607671+00:00 app[web.1]: id: 7171,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607671+00:00 app[web.1]: request_id: 'f4586618-522f-42b0-9021-3d5d5226d13c',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607672+00:00 app[web.1]: request_session: [Object]
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607672+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607672+00:00 app[web.1]: 7457 => {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607672+00:00 app[web.1]: _ns_name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607672+00:00 app[web.1]: id: 7171,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607672+00:00 app[web.1]: request_id: 'f4586618-522f-42b0-9021-3d5d5226d13c',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607673+00:00 app[web.1]: request_session: [Object]
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607673+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607673+00:00 app[web.1]: 7458 => {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607673+00:00 app[web.1]: _ns_name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607673+00:00 app[web.1]: id: 7171,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607673+00:00 app[web.1]: request_id: 'f4586618-522f-42b0-9021-3d5d5226d13c',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607674+00:00 app[web.1]: request_session: [Object]
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607674+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607674+00:00 app[web.1]: 7460 => {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607674+00:00 app[web.1]: _ns_name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607674+00:00 app[web.1]: id: 7171,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607674+00:00 app[web.1]: request_id: 'f4586618-522f-42b0-9021-3d5d5226d13c',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607674+00:00 app[web.1]: request_session: [Object]
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607675+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607675+00:00 app[web.1]: 7461 => {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607675+00:00 app[web.1]: _ns_name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607675+00:00 app[web.1]: id: 7171,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607675+00:00 app[web.1]: request_id: 'f4586618-522f-42b0-9021-3d5d5226d13c',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607675+00:00 app[web.1]: request_session: [Object]
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607675+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607676+00:00 app[web.1]: 7464 => {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607676+00:00 app[web.1]: _ns_name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607676+00:00 app[web.1]: id: 7171,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607676+00:00 app[web.1]: request_id: 'f4586618-522f-42b0-9021-3d5d5226d13c',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607676+00:00 app[web.1]: request_session: [Object]
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607677+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607677+00:00 app[web.1]: 7465 => {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607677+00:00 app[web.1]: _ns_name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607677+00:00 app[web.1]: id: 7171,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607677+00:00 app[web.1]: request_id: 'f4586618-522f-42b0-9021-3d5d5226d13c',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607678+00:00 app[web.1]: request_session: [Object]
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607678+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607678+00:00 app[web.1]: 7466 => {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607678+00:00 app[web.1]: _ns_name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607678+00:00 app[web.1]: id: 7171,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607678+00:00 app[web.1]: request_id: 'f4586618-522f-42b0-9021-3d5d5226d13c',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607678+00:00 app[web.1]: request_session: [Object]
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607679+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607679+00:00 app[web.1]: 7471 => {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607679+00:00 app[web.1]: _ns_name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607679+00:00 app[web.1]: id: 7171,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607679+00:00 app[web.1]: request_id: 'f4586618-522f-42b0-9021-3d5d5226d13c',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607679+00:00 app[web.1]: request_session: [Object]
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607680+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607680+00:00 app[web.1]: 7472 => {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607680+00:00 app[web.1]: _ns_name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607680+00:00 app[web.1]: id: 7171,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607680+00:00 app[web.1]: request_id: 'f4586618-522f-42b0-9021-3d5d5226d13c',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607680+00:00 app[web.1]: request_session: [Object]
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607680+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607681+00:00 app[web.1]: 7475 => {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607681+00:00 app[web.1]: _ns_name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607681+00:00 app[web.1]: id: 7171,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607681+00:00 app[web.1]: request_id: 'f4586618-522f-42b0-9021-3d5d5226d13c',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607681+00:00 app[web.1]: request_session: [Object]
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607681+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607681+00:00 app[web.1]: 7476 => {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607682+00:00 app[web.1]: _ns_name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607682+00:00 app[web.1]: id: 7171,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607682+00:00 app[web.1]: request_id: 'f4586618-522f-42b0-9021-3d5d5226d13c',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607682+00:00 app[web.1]: request_session: [Object]
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607682+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-03-31T08:58:43.614504+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/web/v1/applications/19ae2a2e-b474-45b3-bbf9-cf47ea011210/applicants/18795d35-0c2c-40d2-94c0-5d8ed0b595d5" host=staging-integration.keyzy.com request_id=029bf6e7-afcc-42cf-b072-81c813272785 fwd="90.194.218.36,172.70.85.195" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=14ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=http
2022-03-31T08:58:43.622200+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/web/v1/auth/me" host=staging-integration.keyzy.com request_id=6087ceb5-f064-4252-a8cf-a041efc39ad3 fwd="90.194.218.36,172.70.85.195" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=11ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=http
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607724+00:00 app[web.1]: 7501 => {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607725+00:00 app[web.1]: _ns_name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607725+00:00 app[web.1]: id: 7499,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607725+00:00 app[web.1]: request_id: '5caea1ea-e432-4db9-be20-97063c639ff1'
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607725+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607725+00:00 app[web.1]: 7502 => {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607726+00:00 app[web.1]: _ns_name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607726+00:00 app[web.1]: id: 7499,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607726+00:00 app[web.1]: request_id: '5caea1ea-e432-4db9-be20-97063c639ff1'
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607726+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607726+00:00 app[web.1]: 7503 => {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607726+00:00 app[web.1]: _ns_name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607727+00:00 app[web.1]: id: 7499,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607727+00:00 app[web.1]: request_id: '5caea1ea-e432-4db9-be20-97063c639ff1'
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607727+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607727+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607727+00:00 app[web.1]: _indent: 0
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607727+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607727+00:00 app[web.1]: {
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607728+00:00 app[web.1]: _ns_name: '71963f89-f41a-4211-8339-c55b1d98bfee',
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607728+00:00 app[web.1]: id: 7499,
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607728+00:00 app[web.1]: request_id: '5caea1ea-e432-4db9-be20-97063c639ff1'
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607728+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607728+00:00 app[web.1]: at Namespace.exit (/app/node_modules/cls-hooked/context.js:220:12)
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607728+00:00 app[web.1]: at AsyncHook.after (/app/node_modules/cls-hooked/context.js:407:19)
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607729+00:00 app[web.1]: at emitHook (node:internal/async_hooks:233:38)
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607729+00:00 app[web.1]: at emitAfterScript (node:internal/async_hooks:520:5)
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607729+00:00 app[web.1]: at process._fatalException (node:internal/process/execution:193:11)
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607729+00:00 app[web.1]: at processPromiseRejections (node:internal/process/promises:279:13)
2022-03-31T08:58:43.607730+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:97:32)
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up changing the implementation from `cls-hooked` to `async_hooks`. It fixed the issue and made the flow cleaner :)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and it happened when my app threw an error inside context of cls-hooked. So my solution was to put a try/catch.

If your function ís a promise, use a .catch((err) => {...})

I hope it helps

Comment: Where would you put the try/catch in this scenario?

Comment: @Simon you need to know where the exception occurred, and then put the try/catch. Try see logs in heroku to known that error is happening.